# ssh tunnel not working for external addresses

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I am at a client site and they block some addresses so I am trying to use ssh to tunnel through my company's server. The tunnel works for intranet sites, but it fails  but failing for pubic sites.

This works:
`ssh -L 9291:intranet.bugzilla.com:80 myname@ssh.mycomany.com`

localhost:9291 goes to bugzilla.

But:

`ssh -L 9292:www.yahoo.com:80 myname@ssh.mycomany.com`

doesn't work: localhost:9292 doesn't go to yahoo. It takes me to ssh.mycompany.com's internal address, and then times out

Is there any flag I need to set on ssh.mycompany.com?

Comment: Not directly your question, but it may be better to do something like `ssh -D 9000 myname@ssh.mycompany.com`, and then configure your browser to use a SOCKS proxy at `localhost:9000`. That way, you don't have to manually set up a proxy for each site you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because they are not restricting access to those servers, but simply overloading the DNS records so that an attempt to resolve `www.yahoo.com` from inside your network will point you to some arbitrary server instead of the real `www.yahoo.com` server.

Thats why your SSH trick is not working, because you still rely on what the DNS says when you use hostnames instead of IPs to set up the tunneling.

Try to workaround it by using some other DNS server such as Google's `8.8.8.8`. Maybe you won't even need tunneling to access the site after doing that.